# What design pattern is this?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I have an interface declaring 4 methods  ...
I added an abstract class implementing this interface to give developers the opportunity to choose how many methods they want to implement (specially useful in case of a listener) ...

```
public interface Mylistener {
    void actionA();
    void actionB();
    void actionC();
    void actionD();
}
public abstract class MylistenerWrapper implements Mylistener {
    public void actionA(){}
    public void actionB(){}
    public void actionC(){}
    public void actionD(){}
}
```

and now developers are not obliged to implement all the interface methods :

```
Mylistener l1 = new MylistenerWrapper(){
    public void actionA(){
    //treatment for actionA
    }
    public void actionD(){
    //treatment for actionD
    }
}    
Mylistener l2 = new MylistenerWrapper(){
    public void actionC(){
    //treatment for actionC
    }
}
```

**My question :** what design pattern is this ? I already named my class wrapper (adapter) is it ok ?

Comment: it reeks somehow at Visitor and/or Command but not quite...

Comment: @Lieven: thx !! but it's probably not a 'Visitor' the goal here is not to add new methods but to choose between existent ones ... neither a 'Command' there is no delay call or delegation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapter probably (by analogy with different EventListenerAdapters in `Swing`).